# How to set new php files in PhpStorm to be added directly to Git?

Tags: git, phpstorm

I installed git yesterday and I started using it. I don't know if that options was there before or if it appeared after the installation but I saw today that I had a GIT option in the right click menu in PhpStorm. Now before I realized what it would do I clicked do not show this message again on the pop up window that asked me if I wanted to add the new file to GIT. Now the only I can do that is manually.

Does anyone know where I can find the option for that to set it to automatically adding the files instead of not doing it?

EDIT: to add a pic to clarify: 
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=7380be5

Black files are already commited and pushed.
Green files are added awayting commit and push, or maybe they are commited and awaiting push, I dont know yet what does "add" do.
Red file needs to be added before I can commit and push it.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly stated in the [IntelliJ documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/adding-files-to-a-local-git-repository.html).

You need to open settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) --> Version Control and choose the option "add silently" as shown in photo.
[image]